# Spring boot Spring data mySql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My following entity generated an error when i add these attributes

```
@Size(min=1, max=6)
private String status; 
@Size(min=1, max=2)
private String vip;
@Size(min=1, max=2)
private String sensitive;
```

However when i delete these attributes everything is ok no error found.
I don't know what's wrong with these attributes.
Is someone have an idea to help?

[image]

the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i find the solution. the only attribute which generate the error is sensitive. 
I just rename the attribute to mySensitive and everything is ok now.

Answer (score 2):

That's because SENSITIVE is a [SQL reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).